# Mongoose unwind

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

My order data looks as follows

```
          {
            orderStatus: 'Paid',
            orderItems:
                [{
                    productDeliveryProvider: 'Pending Assignment',
                    productDispatchStatus: 'Pending Assignment',
                    ImageName: 'BRC003.jpeg'
                },
                {
                    productDeliveryProvider: 'Pending Assignment',
                    productDispatchStatus: 'Pending Assignment',
                    ImageName: 'BRC003.jpeg'
                },
                {
                    productDeliveryProvider: 'Paid',
                    productDispatchStatus: 'Paid',
                    ImageName: 'BRC004.jpeg'
                }],
            orderNumber: '#15947327249455',
            
        }
```

I want my end result as follows

```
 {
            orderStatus: 'Paid',
            orderItems:
                [{
                    productDeliveryProvider: 'Pending Assignment',
                    productDispatchStatus: 'Pending Assignment',
                    ImageName: 'BRC003.jpeg'
                },
                {
                    productDeliveryProvider: 'Pending Assignment',
                    productDispatchStatus: 'Pending Assignment',
                    ImageName: 'BRC003.jpeg'
                }],
            orderNumber: '#15947327249455',

        },
 {
            orderStatus: 'Paid',
            orderItems:
                [
                {
                    productDeliveryProvider: 'Paid',
                    productDispatchStatus: 'Paid',
                    ImageName: 'BRC004.jpeg'
                }],
            orderNumber: '#15947327249455',

        }
```

Can anyone please help me on how to group after performing $unwind on orderItems .Initially i have all products in my order but after 1 gets cancelled i want to show the order in both pending as well as paid as it is partially assigned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example solution would `$unwind` and `$group` the elements back but in a different way. For example:

```js
db.getCollection('orders').aggregate([
  // Unwind on "orderItems".
  {$unwind: '$orderItems'},
  {$group: {
    // Group by "orderItems.productDispatchStatus".
    _id: {_id: '$_id', productDispatchStatus: '$orderItems.productDispatchStatus'},
    orderItems: {$push: '$orderItems'},

    // Add all other fields.
    orderStatus: {$first: '$orderStatus'},
    orderNumber: {$first: '$orderNumber'}
  }},
  {$project: {
    // Map "_id" back to the original.
    _id: '$_id._id',

    // Add all other fields.
    orderStatus: 1,
    orderItems: 1,
    orderNumber: 1
  }}
])
```